# Shared Prefrences data are gone after restarting or reopening the app in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Am using the package [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) in my futter application to save login..

**pubspec.yaml**

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  localize_and_translate: ^1.1.1+6
  flutter_fadein: ^1.1.1
  http: ^0.12.2
  loading_overlay: ^0.2.1
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+12
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4  // this line
```

**Saving the data**

```dart
  Future saveLoginData(LoginModel loginModel) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print(loginModel.token); //gives me the right string 
    prefs.setString('theToken', loginModel.token);
    print(prefs.getString('theToken')); //gives me the right string
    prefs.setBool('logged', true);
    prefs.setString('type', 'vendor');
    prefs.setString('mobileNumber', loginModel.username);
}
```

**recalling the data**

```dart
// this function is called while starting the login screen ,to see if the user have to login or just can skip tothe home page
  Future<String> checkIfLogged() async {
    return await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      String theToken = prefs.getString('theToken');
      print(theToken); //outputs null
      return theToken; //returns null
    });
  }
```

When trying to call the saved data in the same opened instance of the app it is being called perfectly, but when the app is closed and checking for data at the `initstate` of the login screen. it gives back null to everything!! a

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way, because you are mixing `await` with the `then` syntax and probably not actually returning

```dart
  Future<String> checkIfLogged() async {
    var prefs= await SharedPreferences.getInstance()
      String theToken = prefs.getString('theToken');
      print(theToken); //outputs null
      return theToken; //returns null
    
  }
```